# Is there an opposite function of pandas.DataFrame.droplevel (like keeplevel)?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Is there an opposite function of `pandas.DataFrame.droplevel` where I can keep some levels of the multi-level index/columns using either the level name or index?

Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame([
        [1, 2, 3, 4],
        [5, 6, 7, 8],
        [9, 10, 11, 12],
        [13, 14, 15, 16]
    ], columns=['a','b','c','d']).set_index(['a','b','c']).T


a   1   5   9   13
b   2   6   10  14
c   3   7   11  15
d   4   8   12  16
```

Both the following commands can return the following dataframe:

```
df.droplevel(['a','b'], axis=1)
df.droplevel([0, 1], axis=1)

c   3   7   11  15
d   4   8   12  16
```

I am looking for a "keeplevel" command such that both the following commands can return the following dataframe:

```
df.keeplevel(['a','b'], axis=1)
df.keeplevel([0, 1], axis=1)

a   1   5   9   13
b   2   6   10  14
d   4   8   12  16
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no `keeplevel` because it would be redundant: in a closed and well-defined set, when you define what you want to drop, you automatically define what you want to keep

You may get the difference from what you have and what `droplevel` returns.

```
def keeplevel(df, levels, axis=1):
    return df.droplevel(df.axes[axis].droplevel(levels).names, axis=axis)
```

---

```
>>> keeplevel(df, [0, 1])

a   1   5   9   13
b   2   6   10  14
d   4   8   12  16
```

Comment: @rafaelc in here , `df.axes[axis].droplevel(levels).names` we create one of the dfs for getting the name to remove

Comment: @WeNYoBen that doesn't return a `df`, just a `pd.MultiIndex` object. It's pretty efficient ;]

Comment: Ah, nice TDL :-)

Answer (score 3):

Using `set` to find the different

```
df.droplevel(list(set(df.columns.names)-set(['a','b'])),axis=1)
Out[134]: 
a 1  5   9   13
b 2  6   10  14
d  4  8  12  16
```

Comment: Thanks, this is efficient, but it would not work if the input is `[0,1]` instead of `['a','b']`, right?

Comment: @GoCurry you can change it to `set(range(len(df.columns.names)))
`

Comment: You are saying `df.droplevel(list(set(range(len(df.columns.names)))-set([0,1])),axis=1)`, right? Then it would not handle the case of `['a','b']`... I am looking for a solution that handles both types of inputs like how `droplevel` can do. I don't want to re-implement the logic that checks whether the inputs are names or levels...

Answer (score 2):

You can modify the Index objects, which should be fast. Note, this will even modify inplace.

```
def keep_level(df, keep, axis):
    idx = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays([df.axes[axis].get_level_values(x) for x in keep])
    df.set_axis(idx, axis=axis, inplace=True)
    return df

keep_level(df.copy(), ['a', 'b'], 1)  # Copy to not modify original for illustration
#a 1  5   9   13
#b 2  6   10  14
#d  4  8  12  16

keep_level(df.copy(), [0, 1], 1)
#a 1  5   9   13
#b 2  6   10  14
#d  4  8  12  16
```